# Apache Spark regexp_replace, replace "\n" for the actual representation?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a [DataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.html) from Spark, I'm trying to remove any newlines and leave the unprocessed \n symbol instead.

Input:

> "Hello
> world"

Expected Result:

> Hello\nWorld

My code snippet is as follows:

```
df.withColumn('discount_description', regexp_replace('discount_description', '\n', r'\n'))
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work if just replaces the text as follows

> Hello**n**World

I also have tried:

- '\\n' -> 'HellonWorld'
- '\\\\n' -> 'Hello\\nWorld'
- repr('\\n') -> 'Hello'\n'World'

Answer (score 0):

Try using two backslashes to escape the `\` preceding `\n`:

```
df.withColumn('discount_description', regexp_replace('discount_description', '\n', '\\n'))
```

Comment: It prints 'HellonWorld'

Comment: @HFR1994 I'm winging it now, but you might need `\\\\n`

Comment: It replaces to Hello\\nWorld @tim-biegeleisen

Comment: I think my first answer is correct, and you have a presentation problem which, for whatever reason, isn't displaying newlines correctly.

Comment: I think it has to do with more with the spark function thing itself because r'\n' should also be an accepted answer. Both results clearly work on a normal python console. (I'm using the debugger before printing the result somewhere else)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing:

```
df.withColumn('discount_description', regexp_replace('discount_description', '\n', r'\\n'))
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is looking for a modern solution to this problem:

```py
df.select(
    F.translate(F.col("discount_description"), "\n", " ").alias("discount_description")
)
```